# Why the Helidon MongoDbStatement doesn't support Sort operations?

Tags: mongodb, helidon, helidon-dbclient

I interested the Helidon SE with MongoDB and my POC requires some REST API with sort support.
I investigated some examples and implementation of helidon-dbclient-mongodb, but I didn't see the sort support.

Will this be implemented in the future or is there a reason why not?

Answer (score 1):

The DbClient in Helidon SE is for abstracting basic operations (CRUD) to enable quick switch of underlying database.
If you need to use something that is part of the Mongo API and cannot be done using the configured queries, you would need to switch to the Mongo DB reactive client directly (instead of using the Helidon DbClient layer).